# Unacknowledged messages on Cloud Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a subscription to a pub/sub topic. My subscriber shows that there are some unacknowledged messages. In last seven days I have around 99 unacknowledged messages and even if pub/sub redeliver them according to the "atleast once delivery policy" then why unacked message count is not reducing? [Unacked message count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJSij.png)

Comment: What is consume your message? Are you sure that the message processing return a HTTP 200 code or that the process doesn't exceed the message delivery timeout? What the logs of the consumer apps are saying?

Comment: could you share the logs you have in both sides? an what type of subscription is it?

Comment: If you have unacked messages, then your subscriber isn't acknowledging messages for some reason.